# Verify that 3 planes belong to the same sheaf of planes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this problem that I can't solve;
I have these 3 planes:

- $x-y+(k-1)z=1$
- $kx + (k+1)z = 0$
- $x+(k-1)y=0$

The question is: find a k that make these planes belonging to the same sheaf of planes. The solution says that, doing the matrix, the det is = 0 for k=0 and k=3, but the system is impossible, so no k is good. I don't understand this solution.

I tried to use Kronecker, choosing a submatrix with det != 0 (and k != -1), and edging it I find that k must be = -1 or k=-1 V k=1. So, the only k that makes R = 2 definitevely is k = - 1, but k = -1 is not ok as solution because k must be != -1 and, so, no k is good. Is this solution ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geometrically:
Planes in the same Sheaf <==> Planes intersect along a line <==> each Plane (equation) is the linear combination of two of the others.

Linear Algebra:
The system of equation admits $\infty^1$ solutions <==> the rank of the coefficient matrix **and of** the total matrix is $2$.

In your case $k=0$ and $k=3$ make the determinant of the coefficient matrix null, and with rank $2$, but the rank of the Total matrix remains $=3$. 
Then the system is impossible.
That's because, while one row of the coefficients is the linear combination of the other, the known terms do not obey to that combination.
Geometrically: the plane orientations are as if they were in the same sheaf, but they are biased of: they meet along three different parallel lines.